# Confirm succesful 'extend' using simr package in R

Tags: r, simulation

I'm using the 'extend' function in simr, but I want to be able to confirm that it has appropriately extended the data set as I wanted it to. Is there a function I can use to show me the data set it has created?

I have a dataset including 17 participants in each of 2 groups. Each participant provided two ratings at each of 8 time points, so that I now have variables of participant (id), the difference between the two ratings (my dependent variable, rating_diff), time (8 levels) and group (2 levels, neutral and threat). As I understand it, id is nested within group.

I constructed the following model and calculated the power to detect an interaction between time and group:

```
model_es <- lmer(rating_diff ~ time + group + time*group + (1|id),
                   data = data)
fixef(model_es)['time:groupthreat'] <- -0.16
interaction_power0 <- powerSim(model_es, nsim=100, test = 
fcompare(rating_diff ~ time + group)) # Power given varies between 86% and 93%, which is too high.
```

I now want to 'extend' the model to determine the power with only 15 participants in each group. First, I checked the number of rows in my existing dataset:

```
nrow(getData(model_es)) # gives 252 rows
```

I worked out that altering the dataset to 15 participants per group should yield 220 rows.
First, I though I ought to be extending within id+group, but that gives too many rows:

```
model_es_extend0 <- extend(model_es, within = 'id+group', n=30)
nrow(getData(model_es_extend0)) # 954 rows
```

I tried extending along id instead:

```
model_es_extend1 <- extend(model_es, along = 'id', n=30)
nrow(getData(model_es_extend1)) #220 rows
```

This clearly gives the correct number of rows, but how can I verify that there are 15 participants per group, rather than 17 still in one group and 13 in the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to check with:

```
xtabs(~ group + time, data=getData(model_es_extend1))
```

I suspect the extend command you want is:

```
model_es_extend2 <- extend(model_es, within = 'time+group', n=15)
```